# How to create a form where user is repetitively prompted for input using microsoft office

Tags: excel, vba, forms, ms-word, office-automation

I want to create a form where user is **repetitively** prompted for input (text), and have that input inserted automatically in a word document.
for instance : I want to automatically insert in a word document as many hobbies as user types in .
How may I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function) function available in VBA. But I think using a form with repetitive input boxes is not really a good decision. Instead, I'd suggest creating a task pane where users could enter the required data.

Comment: How can I write informations continuously in word supposing I can't just leave bookmarks in word to write into since I don't know how many I should put?